# How to print multiple open figures, How to simplify importing data to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, printing, import, figures

I have two questions:

1. I have like twelve open figures in MATLAB (already generated by another function, figure 1 to 12) and I want to print them all to a file, but also to my printer. How can I write the code for that? I already read about getting handles of the figures but I didn't really get the meaning of it and how to print them after that.
2. I wrote a script to import data from many Excel files to MATLAB. The excel files are named so that the only difference is in the the initial part which includes the name/code of the individual person (for whom the information is).

My script looks like this:

```
Indi1_Sim_T_SFTW1= xlsread('E:\MATLAB\Indi1_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls','Indi1_Sim_T_SFTW12')
Indi1_Sim_V_SFTW1= xlsread('E:\MATLAB\Indi1_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls','Indi1_Sim_V_SFTW12')

Indi2_Sim_T_SFTW1= xlsread('E:\MATLAB\Indi2_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls','Indi2_Sim_T_SFTW12')
Indi2_Sim_V_SFTW1= xlsread('E:\MATLAB\Indi2_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls','Indi2_Sim_V_SFTW12')

Indi3_Sim_T_SFTW1= xlsread('E:\MATLAB\Indi3_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls','Indi3_Sim_T_SFTW12')
Indi3_Sim_V_SFTW1= xlsread('E:\MATLAB\Indi3_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls','Indi3_Sim_V_SFTW12')

Indi4_Sim_T_SFTW1= xlsread('E:\MATLAB\Indi4_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls','Indi4_Sim_T_SFTW12')
Indi4_Sim_V_SFTW1= xlsread('E:\MATLAB\Indi4_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls','Indi4_Sim_V_SFTW12')
```

And it goes on for many other individuals.

As you can see, I am repeating the code for each individual. Can I simplify it with a loop function?

P.S: all imported data are numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding bullet no. 1:

> I have open figures in matlab and I want to print them all to a file, but also to my printer.

You have the [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) command for this purpose. Just specify the handle of the figure, for example:

```
print(h)                      %// Send figure with handle h to printer
print(h, '-djpeg', filename)  %// Save figure with handle h to a JPEG file
```

Regarding bullet no. 2:

> ... can I simplify it with a loop function?

Yes you can. You can do something like this:

```
N = 4; %// Number of Excel files
C = cells(2 * N, 1);
for k = 1:2 * N
    filename = sprintf('E:\MATLAB\Indi%d_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls', k);
    C{k} = xlsread(filename, sprintf('Indi%d_Sim_T_SFTW12', k));
    C{k + 1} = xlsread(filename, sprintf('Indi%d_Sim_T_SFTW12', k));
end
```

Now all the data is stored in cell array `C`.

---

#### Explanation

I'm planning to store the output of `xlsread` in a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). You have `N` files and you're reading data from two worksheets per file, and therefore the cell array `C` is initialized with `2 * N` cells.

The `for` loop iterates over each file, and constructs the filename, using the command [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and the iteration counter `k`:

```
filename = sprintf('E:\MATLAB\Indi%d_Output_SFTW1_6min_100_020812.xls', k);
```

The result here is stored in the variable `filename`, and it is passed to the `xlsread` command. The sheet names are also constructed using [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), and passed directly to the `xlsread` without being stored in a variable first.

Q: *Why storing the filename in a variable but not the sheetnames?*
A: I've decided to store the filename in a variable just because I don't want to construct it twice, whereas the sheet names are constructed only once, so storing each of them in a variable bears no significance.

After the loop, the entire data is stored in cell array `C`. To access the i-th element (cell) in C, use curly braces (`{}`). For example, to access the second cell, write `C{2}`.

Q: *Why cell array?*
A: In a cell array each cell can contain data of a different type and length, for instance {2, 'hello'} is a cell array that contains two cells: one contains the number 2 and the other contains the string "hello". Since you cannot guarantee that `xlsread` returns data of the same length, a simple matrix couldn't be used to store the contents of all files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply .. I already tried the first one and it is working perfectly .. thanks ... however, I would like to ask you if 1) there is a possibility to choose the folder where these figures are going to be saved ( rather than automatically in the main MATLAB folder) ?  .. 2) if you could please explain a little bit what you did in your second code, I would appreciate it a lot !

Comment: @Leo... 1) specify the full path for filename and it'll save the file wherever you want. 2) It's just a `for` loop that iterates over the files and invokes `xlsread` for each of them. In every iteration `sprintf` is used to construct the string for the k-th filename string and the sheet name strings. `sprintf` is very similar to `printf` in the C programming language, if you're familiar with it.

Comment: thanks again .. the one with the filepath worked perfectly. The second one I must try it first as I need some time to understand new codes because I am coming from completely different field from programming and Math.

Comment: @Leo... I've included a short explanation, hope this helps.